# Why does my precision change between arrays and lists?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to check for shared elements between two arrays. Here are the arrays and how they are formed:

```
# get range between two values from a df
d = pd.DataFrame([[0.06, 0.81]], columns=['start','stop'])
# rounding to 2 to enforce 2 sig digits
a = np.arange(
            np.around(d.iloc[0]['start'], 2),
            np.around(d.iloc[0]['stop'], 2),
            .01
        )
```

and the other array:

```
b = np.around(0.6999999999999993,2), np.around(1.2400000000000002,2)
b = np.arange(
            b[0],
            b[1],
            .01
        )
```

Now, I want to check if they share any values:

```
bool(set(a) & set(b))
```

This gives me `False`. It should be `True`. It should be true because this is what `a` and `b` look like printed out:

```
# a
array([0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 , 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16,
       0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27,
       0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38,
       0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49,
       0.5 , 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 ,
       0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 , 0.71,
       0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ])

# b
array([0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ,
       0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91,
       0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.  , 1.01, 1.02,
       1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1 , 1.11, 1.12, 1.13,
       1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2 , 1.21, 1.22, 1.23])
```

I get this weird behavior where if I print out `a` and `b` in my jupyter notebook, and then copy and paste the results into new variables and rerun the test, I get `True`. See below:

```
a = [0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 , 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16,
       0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27,
       0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38,
       0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49,
       0.5 , 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 ,
       0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 , 0.71,
       0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ]
b = [0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 ,
       0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91,
       0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.  , 1.01, 1.02,
       1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1 , 1.11, 1.12, 1.13,
       1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2 , 1.21, 1.22, 1.23]

bool(set(a) & set(b))
```

This made me think that the arrays needed to be lists, so I ran this with the original `a` and `b` data:

```
bool(set(list(a)) & set(list(b)))
```

but still `False`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks can be deceiving: Check `for n in a: print(n)`.

Comment: I know, the `n` values all have many digits. Why is this? I though the np.around(n,2) would enforce that all elements in each array were of 2 digits?

Comment: I know that if I do this `a = [round(x,2) for x in list(a)]`, it works, but that seems odd. Why do I need to do this?

Comment: Because `np.arange` is _adding_ floats, with all the side effects that come with it?

Comment: Equality tests on floats are always a problem.  `set` uses equality tests.  `around` still produces floats, so doesn't solve the issue. `np.isclose` and `np.allclose` compare float arrays within floating tolerances.

Comment: Putting float precision issues aside,  `np.in1d(a, b).any()` would indicate if there's any elements in common and be more efficient than pulling data outside of numpy with `set()`.